# How to remove the border bottom for the active element?

Tags: css

I have created a scrollable material UI tab. I have added the border-bottom to the parent element so each tab inside of it will have the bottom line. But here I need to remove the border-bottom for the active tab. I tried but unfortunately, I have no idea how to explicitly remove the border-bottom only to the active tab.

Here you can find the working demo link - https://codesandbox.io/p/github/dhanushkumarsivaji/mui-scrollable-tabs/master?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

**CODE:**

```
import * as React from "react";

import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

import Tabs from "@mui/material/Tabs";

import Tab from "@mui/material/Tab";

import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";

export default function AccessibleTabs1({ hideEditButton = false }) {
  const ButtonContainer = styled("div")(() => ({
    // '@media (max-width: 991px)': {

    //   display: 'none'

    // },

    "& .MuiButton-root": {
      padding: "10px",
    },
  }));

  const TabsContainer = styled(Tabs)(({ theme }) => ({
    "&.tab-container": {
      // background: 'red',

      ".MuiTabs-scroller": {
        borderBottom: `2px solid  ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,
      },

      ".MuiTabs-indicator": {
        display: "none",
      },

      ".MuiTabs-scrollButtons.Mui-disabled": {
        // opacity: 0.3
      },
    },
  }));

  const TabButton = styled(Tab)(({ theme }) => ({
    color: "black !important",

    textTransform: "none",

    padding: "14px",

    fontSize: "24px",

    border: `2px solid  ${theme.palette.common.black}`,

    borderTopLeftRadius: "5px",

    borderTopRightRadius: "5px",

    borderBottom: "none",

    "& :first-of-type": {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },

    margin: "0 10px 0 0",

    "&.Mui-selected": {
      color: `${theme.palette.primary.main} !important`,

      //   border: `2px solid  ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,

      borderTop: `2px solid  ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,

      borderLeft: `2px solid  ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,

      borderRight: `2px solid  ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,

      borderBottom: "none",

      // '& span': {

      //   color: theme.palette.primary.main

      // }
    },
  }));

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  // const tabsData = ["Save For College", "Retirement Saving", "Save For Bike"];

  const tabsData = ["Save For College", "Retirement Saving", "Save For Bike", "Legacy Saving", "Save For Poker", "Save For Money","Save For College", "Retirement Saving", "Save For Bike", "Legacy Saving", "Save For Poker", "Save For Money"]

  return (
    <div style={{marginTop: '60px'}}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={8} lg={8} sm={12}>
          <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <TabsContainer
              className="tab-container"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={value}
              aria-label="Tabs where selection follows focus"
              selectionFollowsFocus
              variant="scrollable"
              scrollButtons
            >
              {tabsData.map((v, i) => (
                <TabButton label={v} />
              ))}

              <TabButton label="+" />
            </TabsContainer>
          </Box>
        </Grid>

        <Grid
          item
          xs={12}
          md={4}
          lg={4}
          sm={12}
          sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}
        >
          {!hideEditButton && (
            <ButtonContainer>
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                onClick={() => {}}
                sx={{ marginRight: "20px" }}
              >
                Get PDF
              </Button>

              <Button
                variant="contained"
                onClick={() => {}}
                sx={{ marginRight: "20px" }}
              >
                Edit Goals
              </Button>
            </ButtonContainer>
          )}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please refer to[image] the attached image. Here I have scribbled a line with red color. Is there any way to remove the line for the active tab?

The expectation has something like this in the below image:

[image]

Please let me know the possibilities of it or is there any way we can achieve this

**Answer Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: codesandbox link is readonly so cant do changes and test to find proper solution. if you remove read only, I may be able to help. what you are asking is already implemented in bootstrap library.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the forked working code that solves your problem [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/AkisKouzinopoulos/mui-scrollable-tabs-solution/draft/boring-frost?file=%2Fsrc%2Ftabs.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A19%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A93%2C%22startColumn%22%3A19%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A93%7D%5D&create=true&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cl9mr0a8h0002lsh049e334dz%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252Fsrc%252Ftabs.js%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl9mr2mkt00k83b6oisd6jbrz%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D)

To explain:
The problem is coming from the

```
".MuiTabs-scroller": {
   borderBottom: `2px solid  ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,
},
```

you need to set it to `none` or just remove it, because is covering any other border contained inside it.

Then you can add a similar border that will run across the whole tab container by adding on the same element an `after` like this:

```
".MuiTabs-scroller:after": {
    content: `""`,
    width: "100%",
    height: "2px",
    background: "#1976d2",
    position: "absolute",
    top: "58px",
    zIndex: "1",
  },
```

Then using a similar method you add another `after` to the selected tab that will contain an element with white `background` that will hide the blue border from the tab container giving you the desired result, like this:

```
"&:after": {
    content: `""`,
    width: "calc(100% + 32px)",
    boxShadow: "0px -1px 0px 2px white",
    top: "14px",
    background: "white",
    position: "relative",
    zIndex: "100",
  },
```

Comment: @SDK did you check the solution on the codesandbox? It should work and is solving your problem

Comment: I have checked your solution, there is a small miss in that. That you have added the content width after, is not taking up the whole scrollable section. I have attached the screenshot FYR. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I see what you mean. Seems is happening because of the `overflow-x`. A good fix is to identify the width of the scrollable content and pass it to the `".MuiTabs-scroller:after"` instead of using `width: 100%`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the border on the bottom is of one of the parent elements, you could try adding a shadow to the bottom of the selected: `box-shadow: 0 4px 0 -2px white` [Example here](https://codepen.io/aracsidev/pen/XWYrrGR)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the border bottom to the `.MuiTabs-flexContainer`. It is the parent element of the tabs. Then you need to apply a white `box-shadow` only at the bottom of the active tab.

Try to apply the below styles in you code, it will work.

```
      '.MuiTabs-flexContainer': {
        borderBottom: `2px solid  ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,
        width: '100%',
        minWidth: 'max-content'
      }
```

```
    '&.Mui-selected': {
      color: `${theme.palette.primary.main} !important`,
      borderTop: `2px solid  ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,
      borderLeft: `2px solid  ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,
      borderRight: `2px solid  ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,
      borderBottom: 'none',
      boxShadow: '0 4px 0 -2px white'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a white border to chosen tab instead of removing or hiding the border.

Comment: hi, I tried that but it doesn't works :(

Answer (score 0):

On active tab .Mui-selected this class is being added so use it in your styling `.Mui-selected{ border-bottom: none !important; }`

Comment: Hi Nope its not working